# Which Galois Field is isomorphic to this extension?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

Let $\alpha$ be an element in an algebraic closure of $GF(64)$ such that $\alpha^4=\alpha+1$. For which $r\in \mathbb{N}$ is $GF(64)$ adjoined $\alpha$ isomorphic to $GF(2^r)$?

[Adding the following bit by the OP from the comments, JL]

Since is $\alpha$ a root of the irreducible polynomial $x^4+x+1$ the degree of its minimal polynomial over $GF(2)$ i four. So $\alpha$ is in $GF(16)$. But $GF(16)$ is not a subfield of $GF(64)$, so I'm not sure where to go with this.

Comment: What's the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\;\alpha\;$ over $\;\Bbb F_2\;$?

Comment: The degree is 4, since $\alpha$ is a root of the irreducible polynomial $x^4+x+1$. So $\alpha$ is in $GF(16)$. But $GF(16)$ is not a subfield of $GF(64)$, so I'm not sure where to go with this.

Comment: So what's the smallest field containing both GF(64) and GF(16)?

Comment: Snowflake, Gerry's hint is the way to go. Do you remember the condition when $GF(2^m)$ is a subfield of $GF(2^n)$? And, your reasoning leading to $\alpha\in GF(16)$ is correct. +1 for that.

Comment: And it is best to add comments showing your own thinking to the main question. That dispels the thoughts that you wanted to assign your homework problem to us. Your ability to answer Timbuc's question goes a long way. The members who voted to put the question on hold were concerned about lack of such (or other) context in your question. I put it in there to get the voting to reopen to begin. You probably should edit the question more.

Comment: Since $lcm(6,4)=12$, the smallest field containing both $GF(64)$ and $GF(16)$ will be $GF(2^{12})$. So $r=12$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $E$ be an algebraic closure of $GF(64)$ and $\alpha \in E$ such that $\alpha^4 = \alpha + 1$. Raising both terms to the fourth power and using $char(E)=2$ you get that $\alpha^{16} = \alpha^4+1$. Doing that again, $\alpha^{64} = \alpha^{16}+1$. Combine this three equalities to get $\alpha^{64} = \alpha+3=\alpha+1$. This tells you that $\alpha$ is a root of $X^{64}-X-1$.

Now remember that $GF(64)$ is exactly the set of roots of $X^{64}-X$ in $E$. If $\alpha$ were in $GF(64)$, then $\alpha$ would be a common root of $X^{64}-X$ and $X^{64}-X-1$. But then $X-\alpha$ would be a factor of $(X^{64}-X) - (X^{64}-X-1) = 1$ which is an absurd. So $\alpha$ is not in $GF(64)$.

Looking at $f=X^4+X+1$ you discover that if $\gamma\in E$ is a root of $f$ then $\gamma+1$ and $\gamma^2$ are also roots of $f$ in $E$. Keep in mind that $char(E)=2$. With this information you can factor $f$ like this $$f=X^4+X+1=(X^2+X+(\alpha^2+\alpha))(X^2+X+(\alpha^2+\alpha+1))$$

If we prove that $\alpha^2+\alpha$ is in $GF(64)$ then $g=X^2+X+(\alpha^2+\alpha)$ is in $GF(64)[X]$ and $g(\alpha)=0$. So the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $GF(64)$ divides $g$. Because $\alpha$ is not in $GF(64)$ then $g$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $GF(64)$. This gives $[GF(64)(\alpha):GF(64)]= 2$ and then $[GF(64)(\alpha):GF(2)]=2\cdot6=12$. So $r=12$.

Let's prove that $\alpha^2+\alpha$ is in $GF(64)$. Put $\beta = \alpha^2+\alpha$. Now $\beta^2=\alpha^4+\alpha^2$ and $\beta^2-\beta=\alpha^4-\alpha = 1$. This gives $\beta^2+\beta+1=0$. Multiply by $\beta - 1$ to obtain $\beta^3-1=0$. Multiply by $\beta$ to give $\beta^4 = \beta$. Raise to the fourth power and $\beta^{16}=\beta^4=\beta$. Do it again and $\beta^{64}= \beta$. This proves that $\beta$ is a root in $E$ of $X^{64}-X$ and then $\beta\in GF(64)$.